# How to ask a question about code in an answer?

Tags: discussion

This Q&A has an amazing amount of density: [How to emulate C array initialization "int arr[] = { e1, e2, e3, ... }" behaviour with std::array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114067/how-to-emulate-c-array-initialization-int-arr-e1-e2-e3-behaviou)

Is it reasonable to use Programmers.Stack to ask for deep explanations of an answer?  (Example: Puppy's is so.... dense to me.)

Why do I think this is valuable to the Stack network?  Other readers may be interested to see "blow-by-blow" analysis of super dense answers.

Comment: It may help to comment on that post asking for elaboration - the user is still active. Worth being a first step.

Comment: What does "amazing of density" mean?

Comment: I don't think that's the kind of clarification that belongs in comments, @Cube. Explaining what the code means and how it works would be far too long for a comment, and not related to the question that the answer is actually answering. Kevinarpe is right in thinking he should ask a new question about it. Of course, if it's a syntactical question about C++ constructs, it would be perfectly on-topic for Stack Overflow. Rather than asking for a "blow-by-blow analysis" (which is too broad and won't go over well on SO), ask for clarification on the *specific parts* you don't understand.

Comment: @Cody I'm implying the explanation would be in the form of an edit to the answer.  =)

Answer (score 8):

I took a look at Programmer's tour, and it starts with this:

> Programmers Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for professionals and students in software development and related fields who are interested in getting expert answers on **conceptual questions** about software development.

(Emphasis mine).

I also took a cursory look at the most upvoted questions they have. They go more along the lines of:

- What technical details should a programmer of a web application consider before making the site public?
- Which hashing algorithm is best for uniqueness and speed?
- Where did the notion of “one return only” come from?
- Why is 80 characters the 'standard' limit for code width?

I have a gut feeling that asking for an expanded explanation of a very specific answer to a very specific problem may not be welcome there. Maybe if you could write your questions so as to be more conceptual, though, such as in "why is this alghorithm/heuristic/logic the most appropriate solution to this kind of problem"... then you could maybe post it there, but I'd still recommend trying to post rather into SO, or maybe into [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) (another Programmer's and SO's sister stack).

Comment: Please do look at the help center for any Stack Exchange site you are thinking of posting on. The most upvoted questions do not necessarily indicate what's on topic. Stack Overflow has many old, upvoted questions which are not on topic on today's Stack Overflow.

Answer (score -2):

You could request an improvement to the to [Documentation Topic about C++ arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/2712/stdarray#t=201608242210229292776) which could go into the detail that you believe would be beneficial to the community.